# Python Data Munging | Differences in Data Frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This question is inspired from [R Programming | Pre-Processing / Formatting Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70931867/r-programming-pre-processing-formatting-data), but looking to do something similar with Python3.

Here are example data frames:

```
df1 = {'Item': ["ABCDEF", "FEDCBA", "AA-BB-CCCC", "ABCDEFGH-IJK", "ZZZZ"], 'ID' : ['X','1','2','3','4'], 'Quant' : ['1','5','AR','5','2']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)


df2 = {'Item': ["ABCDEF", "FEDCBA:XA", "AA-BB-CCCC-01", "AA-BB-CCCC-21:ABC", "ABCDEFGH-IJK-1X", "AKDWXFE-XXY"], 'ID' : ['1','2','3','3','4','5'], 'Quant' : ['1','5','3.2','3.2','5','2']} 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)

print("Python equivalent of R's 'str' function for df1:")
df1.info()

print("Python equivalent of R's 'str' function for df2:")
df2.info()
```

Here is a view of the data frames:
[image]

Finding differences in the 'Items' column is most crucial.  If not willing to refer to [R Programming | Pre-Processing / Formatting Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70931867/r-programming-pre-processing-formatting-data) for a more comprehensive review, python equivalent of the following R code will help:

```
library(tidyverse)
                            
df1_has_match <- map_lgl(df1, ~ any(grepl(., df2)))
msg <- sprintf("Add [%s]", df1[ !df1_has_match ])

map1 <- map_dfr(df1, ~ set_names(grepl(., df2), df2))

df2_has_match <- map_lgl(map1, any)
msg <- c(msg, 
         sprintf("delete [%s]", df2[ !df2_has_match ]))

cat(msg, sep="\n")
```

Any tips on how to also do this for the 'ID' and 'Quant' fields would also be of great appreciation.

Per request, adding an expected layout/result (something similar would work, too):

[image]

Adding summary view, as requested:

[image]

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: An expected output would be a data frame depicting the differences between the two.  

An example of a non-difference would be "AA-BB-CCCC" and ""AA-BB-CCCC-21:ABC", since each contain the "AA-BB-CCCC" base item, if that makes sense.

Comment: To clarify, df1 is the 'correct' list.  That is, if there are differences between the two, I would need to correct df2 in order to match df1.

The tricky part are those partial similarities (i.e., AA-BB-CCCC is an accepted partial match of AA-BB-CCCC-21:ABC).

Comment: could you include the df that you expect in your question

Comment: Your image shows the procedure on df1 instead of df2. Also, we only need the final df2. Not the procedure. Just give the final df2 that you want

Comment: I've added a summary picture now, just including changes.  Would this help? @onyambu

Comment: This is confusing. Are you changing df1 or df2? You say when item is ABCDEF change id from 1 to X ie changing df2, but when item is FEDCBA change id from 1 to 2 meaning we are changing df1. What exactly are you changing? df1 or df2??

Comment: @onyambu Comparing df1 to df2.  Attempting to inform the user how df2 needs to change in order to conform to df1.  The tricky part is the partial match aspect.  For example, AA-BB-CCCC-21:ABC and AA-BB-CCCC would be considered partial matches.

First screenshot tells the reader what needs to change in both data frames, the second screenshot is a combination of the two -- only changes.

Comment: The matching is easy, whatis difficult is what exactly are you trying to change?

Comment: Essentially looking to see the differences between df1 and df2 and summarize it.  The tricky part is the partial match aspect.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include your user name @onyambu ^

Comment: Yeah did not get a notification. I had already matched it. O was just curious as to what to fo after the matching. I used `difflib.get_close_matches`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245127/discussion-between-helpmecode-and-onyambu).

Comment: @onyambu also wondering about this.  Would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, i rarely look at SO on weekends unless its paid.

Comment: Are you still stuck on these?

Comment: I am, but willing to wait for a non-holiday week day. @onyambu

Comment: Its fine, let me check how I can Help. You can visit my page too

Answer (score 0):

To merge the two tables, consider the following:

```
from difflib import get_close_matches
df1['Item_2'] = df1.Item.apply(get_close_matches, args = [df2.Item])
df1.explode('Item_2').merge(df2, left_on = 'Item_2', right_on = 'Item')

 
         Item_x ID_x Quant_x             Item_2             Item_y ID_y Quant_y
0        ABCDEF    X       1             ABCDEF             ABCDEF    1       1
1  ABCDEFGH-IJK    3       5             ABCDEF             ABCDEF    1       1
2        FEDCBA    1       5          FEDCBA:XA          FEDCBA:XA    2       5
3    AA-BB-CCCC    2      AR      AA-BB-CCCC-01      AA-BB-CCCC-01    3     3.2
4    AA-BB-CCCC    2      AR  AA-BB-CCCC-21:ABC  AA-BB-CCCC-21:ABC    3     3.2
5  ABCDEFGH-IJK    3       5    ABCDEFGH-IJK-1X    ABCDEFGH-IJK-1X    4       5
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not necessarily looking to just merge the tables, @onyambu

Comment: @HelpMeCode i did merge them so that you can try the rest. Your difficulty was to merge them. Once you have merged, you can manipulate them the way you want. Eg if you want to cange item × to item y, you have the 2 colums side by side and you can compare them accordingly

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot accept that answer, but thank you for your efforts. @onyambu

Comment: @HelpMeCode Thats fine. Could you include the final results that you want?  Not the changes you want to make but rather the exact table that you want

Comment: it would be the second screenshot (would be two data frames as output).  Alternatively, the 3rd screenshot would be a desired data frame output. @onyambu

Comment: @HelpMeCode note that the screenshots have the changes to be made rather than the made changes themselves. The reason why I am asking this is because `df1` already has ID = X for ABCDEF yet you want to change it from 1 to X which does not make sense. It is already X, how do you change it to X again? So instead of writing what the changes SHOULD BE include a table with the changes having taken plane

Comment: The entire objective is to provide comments on how to make DF2 become DF1.  In that example, DF2's instance of the fragment 'ABDEF' would need to have its ID changed from 1 to X in order to comply. @onyambu

Comment: @HelpMeCode you should consider asking a new question

Comment: It would largely be worded the same -- and then someone else would just mark it as a duplicate. @onyambu

Comment: @HelpMeCode The problem is I dont understand your question. And frankly speaking, the merge above does 3/4 of the job. You can then extract whatever data you want from the merge. Probably a fresh set of eyes/ears/mind would help you solve the problem. Also note that you can delete this and ask a new question or word the new question differently, be sure it wont be marked as duplicate. Better try than not.